# selecionar numero de files com np.random.choice, usando o parametro replace

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, números-aleatórios

Por exemplo, preciso selecionar 5 de arquivos aleatórios de um diretório que contém 10K+

```
imgs = os.listdir(path_src)
# pegar 5 imagens aleatorias
random_imgs = np.random.choice(imgs, int(n_images), replace=False)  

for img in random_imgs:
    if img.endswith(".jpg"):
        src = os.path.join(path_src, img)
        dest = os.path.join(path_dest, img)
        shutil.move(src, dest)
```

Usei replace=False para não repetir o mesmo arquivo quando for mover para outro diretório.
o n_images mostra até quantas imagens devem ser selecionadas
imgs é a variável que armazena o caminho do diretório de imagens

Não consigo usar np.random.choice, mesmo vendo a documentação nunca são selecionadas as 5 imagens, sempre são selecionadas menos que isso de 2 a 3 imagens, mas preciso de 5 imagens. Então n_images deve ser de outra forma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem certeza que todos os arquivos na pasta são imagens e as extensões das imagens são todas .jpg e sem espaços a mais? Eu tentei aqui e deu certo! Altere seu código para englobar outras extensões adicionando .PNG também: (pois a lista random_imgs está pegando as 5 imagens (ou 5 arquivos, se tiver outros arquivos sem ser imagens na pasta), o problema está no IF, é preciso garantir que as extensões das imagens vão cair na condição)

```
for img in random_imgs:
    if img.endswith(".png") or img.endswith(".jpg"):
        src = os.path.join(path_src, img)
        dest = os.path.join(path_dest, img)
        shutil.move(src, dest)
```

Em caso de duvida, use:

```
print(random_imgs)
```

no código para ver quais os 5 arquivos que estão sendo selecionados, assim você consegue entender melhor o problema

Comment: Por falta de atenção tinha tanta certeza, que não debuguei. Muito obrigada.